# Mapping a Variable in an Absolute URL using Thymleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, html-email

I'm writing an HTML email template and I'm trying to use thymleaf to map a variable (username) in a hyperlink.

So my URL looks like this: `https://example.com/#/login?username=johndoe`

I have tried the following but the mapping didn't work as expected

```
<p> <a th:href="@{https://example.com/#/login(username=${username})}">https://example.com/#/login?username=${username}</a></p>
```

I wasn't expecting the second part of the mapping to work correctly.

My desired output is something like this:

```
<p> <a href="https://example.com/#/?/login?username=johndoe">https://example.com/#/?/login?username=johndoe</a></p>
```

Any help would be appreciated it. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... you're saying the url is working correctly, but the text in between the `<a></a>` tags doesn't look like you want?

Comment: No the url is not working correctly the variable doesn't map

Comment: Well, the syntax you have is correct, so are you sure you have data in `$username`? And what do you mean "but the mapping didn't work as expected".  What is the output you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like

```
<p> <a th:href="@{'https://example.com/#/login?username='+ ${username}}">https://example.com/#/login?username=${username}</a></p
```